# Problems installing FortiClient on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, update-manager, repository

My company asked us to set up and test remote connections to be able to work from home for the next weeks. They want me to install FortiClient for the VPN connection.
I followed the steps here:

https://www.forticlient.com/repoinfo

but got errors during the process. Can someone hint to what I can do?

```
tmt@pallascat:~$ wget -O - https://repo.fortinet.com/repo/ubuntu/DEB-GPG-KEY | sudo apt-key add -
[sudo] password for tmt: --2020-03-15 19:35:58--  https://repo.fortinet.com/repo/ubuntu/DEB-GPG-KEY
Resolving repo.fortinet.com (repo.fortinet.com)... 208.91.114.61
Connecting to repo.fortinet.com (repo.fortinet.com)|208.91.114.61|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1020
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

-                   100%[===================>]    1020  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2020-03-15 19:35:59 (182 MB/s) - written to stdout [1020/1020]


tmt@pallascat:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for tmt: 
Hit:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]    
Hit:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease           
Get:5 https://repo.fortinet.com/repo/ubuntu /bionic InRelease [1.916 B]        
Err:5 https://repo.fortinet.com/repo/ubuntu /bionic InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 18AC26395E54716D
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://repo.fortinet.com/repo/ubuntu /bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 18AC26395E54716D
E: The repository 'https://repo.fortinet.com/repo/ubuntu /bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: It's not clear what command you ran exactly for the "install gpg key" part, but it's clear that it was not completed correctly.

Comment: I followed the steps from their website:
```wget -O - https://repo.fortinet.com/repo/ubuntu/DEB-GPG-KEY | sudo apt-key add - ```

Answer (score 1):

I searched a bit further and found this thread here on askubuntu:

[How do I fix the GPG error "NO_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

That worked.  :)